# Does Lua have a way to pull files with naming conventions?

Tags: lua

So I am working on a project where I am attempting to pull one of X number of sounds randomly, using a random number generation to decide what sound to play. I'm wondering if it's feasible to have all the filenames use a naming convention that ends with a number, and instead of needing to input all the filenames I could just change the random number generation to the number of files.

It would be formatted something like this:

```
function onCreate()
  dodgeSound = 1;
  precacheSound('Dodge1');
  precacheSound('Dodge2');
  precacheSound('Dodge3');
end

function noteMiss --a custom function
 dodgeSound = math.random(1, 3);
 playSound('Dodge'dodgeSound, 0.7);
end
```

Is this a feasible way to do this, and are there any specific formatting issues I need to keep in mind in order to make this work? Am I better off just sucking it up and having if functions checking for which sound to play? Is there a better way I could be doing this to begin with?

Comment: `'Dodge'..dodgeSound`...

Comment: You can put file names into array, then select random element of array; this way you will not depend on file naming convention

Comment: You don't need the semicolons, your `noteMiss` has two syntax errors (should be `function noteMiss()` and what shingo pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table to store the sounds, and then set the max of your random call to the length of the table. This is more flexible as the `noteMiss` function no longer needs to be updated if you add a new sound you simply add it to the `dodgeSounds` table and the code handles the rest.

```lua
function onCreate()
    dodgeSounds = {
      'Dodge1',
      'Dodge2',
      'Dodge3',
    }
  
    for _, sound in ipairs(dodgeSounds) do
      precacheSound(sound)
    end
end

function noteMiss()
    selected = math.random(1, #dodgeSounds)
    playSound(dodgeSounds[selected], 0.7)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate file paths like this

```lua
local Sounds = {
    path = "../Sounds/",
    filenameExt = ".ogg",
    __call = function(self)
        math.randomseed(os.time())
        self.path = self.path .. self.type .. math.random(self.quantity) .. self.filenameExt
        return self
    end
}
Sounds.__index = Sounds

function Sounds:play(volume)
    -- ... play sound logic
    print("type: ", self.type)
    print("path: ", self.path)
    print("volume: ", volume)
end

local dodgeSound =
    setmetatable(
    {
        type = "Dodge",
        quantity = 3
    },
    Sounds
)

dodgeSound():play(0.7)
```